# nodemailer-express-handlebars | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory for template !! node.js

Tags: html, node.js, express, nodemailer, express-handlebars

1. I am trying to send a template form node js using nodemailer and express-handlebars but I'm getting the error no such file I have no idea what I'm missing
2. I'm attaching my index.js down

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const hb = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
 const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
 const { google } = require('googleapis');
 const path = require('path');

// These id's and secrets should come from .env file.
 const CLIENT_ID = 'the id';
 const CLEINT_SECRET = 'the secret';
 const REDIRECT_URI = 'uri';
 const REFRESH_TOKEN = 'the token';

 const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
   CLIENT_ID,
   CLEINT_SECRET,
   REDIRECT_URI
 );
 oAuth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });



app.post("/api", async (req,res) => {
    try{
    const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: 'your [enter image description here][1]emial',
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: CLEINT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: REFRESH_TOKEN,
        accessToken: accessToken,
      },
    })
    
    const handlebarOptions = {
        viewEngine: {
          extName: ".handlebars",
          partialsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "emialTemplate"),
          defaultLayout: false,
        },
        viewPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "emialTemplate"),
        extName: ".handlebars",
      };
      
      transport.use(
        "compile",
        hb(handlebarOptions)
      );

   // the data which we going to send

    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.name + '<ummed.gagrana@gmail.com>',
        to: 'ummed.gagrana@gmail.com',
        subject: req.body.subject,
        text: "From:" + req.body.email + "\n Message:" + req.body.message,
        //   html: '<h2>From:</h2>'+'<h4>'+req.body.email+"</h4> <br>"+"<h2>Message:</h2>"+'<h4>'+req.body.message+"</h4>",
        template: 'comeBack'
    };
   //sending mail

       const result = await transport.sendMail(mailOptions);

   // checking the result after sending mail
        console.log(result)
        res.send({hey:"well done you just paased some data"})

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("server up and running on port 3000")
})
```

4. This the code I am not sure what I'm missing I'm a beginner in nodejs so please help
5. I am attaching my work directory path for help

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo. **emialTemplate --> emailTemplate**

```js
const handlebarOptions = {
        viewEngine: {
          extName: ".handlebars",
          partialsDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "emailTemplate"),
          defaultLayout: false,
        },
        viewPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "emailTemplate"),
        extName: ".handlebars",
      };
```

After that, I would return the following code line to tell the server that the code has been processed as it should have.

```js
return res.send({hey:"well done you just paased some data"})
```